# Bulk resolving iTunes media locations

Tags: mac, itunes

Is there a way to force resolve media information for all songs?

I have multiple computers (2 Macs, 1 PC) where all of the songs for their iTunes' libraries are on my Time Capsule at home. However, when I take my Mac laptop to work and come back home, all of my songs in iTunes have the "exclamation point" indicating that their locations cannot be found (because I disconnected from my Time Capsule and then re-connected).

It's not a problem until I try to sync music to my iPod, where iTunes will only sync "unbroken" songs, so I end up with no music on my iPod.

I could "Get Info" for all tracks manually, one-by-one, but I'd really rather not. Also, I'd like to avoid operations that make me lose my metadata (like ratings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after a LOT of searching I found my fix:

Hold Alt/Option while opening iTunes, it will bring up a dialog allowing you to choose the location of your iTunes library. Choose your existing library location, and voila... all songs are "magically" located. Ratings, play count etc. is saved. Phew!

Comment: I don't quite get it... Every time you get back from work and want to sync your ipod, you do this process?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar NAS and network shared folder setup, and can end up with an iTunes library full of exclamation marks in some circumstances.

To fix this I use [sed](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/sed.1.html) to replace all instances of:

```
<key>File Folder Count</key><integer>-1</integer>
```

...with:

```
<key>File Folder Count</key><integer>1</integer>
```

...where a "File Folder Count" of -1 equates to iTunes thinking the file is missing.  Using sed:

```
sed -i .backup 's/<key>File Folder Count<\/key><integer>-1<\/integer>/<key>File Folder Count<\/key><integer>1<\/integer>"/g' ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Music\ Library.xml
```